# ssrs - grouping rows one per page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have data that looks like this

[image]

Now in SSRS I am trying to create a report **GROUPED ON** Invoice ID. Basically here is the end result I would like

[image]

If someone can give me step by step instructions on how to do this in SSRS, It would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Start by writing an efficient stored procedure and return the data.
2. Add a matrix with a detail row in the bottom row/column groups panes.
3. The row group created in step 2 should have the group Field Set to Fields!InvoiceID.Value
4. Order the group by Fields!InvoiceID.Value
5. Add a header/subtotal before or a footer/subtotal after the group based on InvoiceID.
6. Make another group to store detail data of the invoiceID in the footer of the report.

This should work.